# Errors while starting WSO2 API Manager 2.1.0

Tags: wso2-api-manager, wso2

I am getting errors and warnings while trying to bring up WSO2 API Manager 2.1.0 for the first time. [CentOS Linux release 7.3.1611 (Core)]. Excerpts are given below. I have already tried the suggestions at: [Failed to start wso2 API Manager v2.0.0 on centos 7.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38948303/failed-to-start-wso2-api-manager-v2-0-0-on-centos-7-0)

```
$ ./wso2server.sh
JAVA_HOME environment variable is set to /usr/java/jdk1.8.0_60
CARBON_HOME environment variable is set to /home/devwso2/wso2am-2.1.0
Using Java memory options: -Xms256m -Xmx1024m
[2017-02-22 06:03:46,688]  INFO - QpidBundleActivator Setting BundleContext in PluginManager
[2017-02-22 06:03:48,217]  INFO - CarbonCoreActivator Starting WSO2 Carbon...
[2017-02-22 06:03:48,217]  INFO - CarbonCoreActivator Operating System : Linux 3.10.0-514.6.1.el7.x86_64, amd64
[2017-02-22 06:03:48,218]  INFO - CarbonCoreActivator Java Home        : /usr/java/jdk1.8.0_60/jre
[2017-02-22 06:03:48,218]  INFO - CarbonCoreActivator Java Version     : 1.8.0_60
[2017-02-22 06:03:48,218]  INFO - CarbonCoreActivator Java VM          : Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM 25.60-b23,Oracle Corporation
[2017-02-22 06:03:48,218]  INFO - CarbonCoreActivator Carbon Home      : /home/devwso2/wso2am-2.1.0
[2017-02-22 06:03:48,218]  INFO - CarbonCoreActivator Java Temp Dir    : /home/devwso2/wso2am-2.1.0/tmp
[2017-02-22 06:03:48,218]  INFO - CarbonCoreActivator User             : devwso2, en-US, UTC
[2017-02-22 06:03:48,387]  WARN - ValidationResultPrinter Swap Memory size (MB): 0 of the system is below the recommended minimum size :2047
[2017-02-22 06:03:48,389]  WARN - ValidationResultPrinter Carbon is configured to use the default keystore (wso2carbon.jks). To maximize security when deploying to a production environment, configure a new keystore with a unique password in the production server profile.
.....................

[2017-02-22 06:04:46,407] ERROR - Main Exception during startup. Triggering shutdown 
org.wso2.andes.kernel.AndesException: Unable to initialise application registry
    at org.wso2.andes.server.Broker.startupImpl(Broker.java:308)
    at org.wso2.andes.server.Broker.startup(Broker.java:110)
    at org.wso2.andes.server.Main.startBroker(Main.java:217)
    at org.wso2.andes.server.Main.execute(Main.java:206)
    at org.wso2.andes.server.Main.<init>(Main.java:54)
    at org.wso2.andes.server.Main.main(Main.java:47)
    at org.wso2.carbon.andes.internal.QpidServiceComponent.startAndesBroker(QpidServiceComponent.java:420)
    at org.wso2.carbon.andes.internal.QpidServiceComponent.activate(QpidServiceComponent.java:165)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.model.ServiceComponent.activate(ServiceComponent.java:260)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.model.ServiceComponentProp.activate(ServiceComponentProp.java:146)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.model.ServiceComponentProp.build(ServiceComponentProp.java:345)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.InstanceProcess.buildComponent(InstanceProcess.java:620)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.InstanceProcess.buildComponents(InstanceProcess.java:197)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.Resolver.getEligible(Resolver.java:343)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.SCRManager.serviceChanged(SCRManager.java:222)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.FilteredServiceListener.serviceChanged(FilteredServiceListener.java:107)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.dispatchEvent(BundleContextImpl.java:861)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:230)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.ListenerQueue.dispatchEventSynchronous(ListenerQueue.java:148)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceRegistry.publishServiceEventPrivileged(ServiceRegistry.java:819)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceRegistry.publishServiceEvent(ServiceRegistry.java:771)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceRegistrationImpl.register(ServiceRegistrationImpl.java:130)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceRegistry.registerService(ServiceRegistry.java:214)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.registerService(BundleContextImpl.java:433)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.registerService(BundleContextImpl.java:451)
    at org.wso2.carbon.server.admin.internal.ServerAdminServiceComponent.activate(ServerAdminServiceComponent.java:106)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.model.ServiceComponent.activate(ServiceComponent.java:260)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.model.ServiceComponentProp.activate(ServiceComponentProp.java:146)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.model.ServiceComponentProp.build(ServiceComponentProp.java:345)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.InstanceProcess.buildComponent(InstanceProcess.java:620)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.InstanceProcess.buildComponents(InstanceProcess.java:197)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.Resolver.getEligible(Resolver.java:343)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.SCRManager.serviceChanged(SCRManager.java:222)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.FilteredServiceListener.serviceChanged(FilteredServiceListener.java:107)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.dispatchEvent(BundleContextImpl.java:861)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:230)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.ListenerQueue.dispatchEventSynchronous(ListenerQueue.java:148)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceRegistry.publishServiceEventPrivileged(ServiceRegistry.java:819)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceRegistry.publishServiceEvent(ServiceRegistry.java:771)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceRegistrationImpl.register(ServiceRegistrationImpl.java:130)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceRegistry.registerService(ServiceRegistry.java:214)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.registerService(BundleContextImpl.java:433)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.registerService(BundleContextImpl.java:451)
    at org.wso2.carbon.core.init.CarbonServerManager.initializeCarbon(CarbonServerManager.java:514)
    at org.wso2.carbon.core.init.CarbonServerManager.start(CarbonServerManager.java:219)
    at org.wso2.carbon.core.internal.CarbonCoreServiceComponent.activate(CarbonCoreServiceComponent.java:94)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.model.ServiceComponent.activate(ServiceComponent.java:260)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.model.ServiceComponentProp.activate(ServiceComponentProp.java:146)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.model.ServiceComponentProp.build(ServiceComponentProp.java:345)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.InstanceProcess.buildComponent(InstanceProcess.java:620)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.InstanceProcess.buildComponents(InstanceProcess.java:197)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.Resolver.getEligible(Resolver.java:343)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.SCRManager.serviceChanged(SCRManager.java:222)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.FilteredServiceListener.serviceChanged(FilteredServiceListener.java:107)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.dispatchEvent(BundleContextImpl.java:861)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:230)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.ListenerQueue.dispatchEventSynchronous(ListenerQueue.java:148)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceRegistry.publishServiceEventPrivileged(ServiceRegistry.java:819)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceRegistry.publishServiceEvent(ServiceRegistry.java:771)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceRegistrationImpl.register(ServiceRegistrationImpl.java:130)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceRegistry.registerService(ServiceRegistry.java:214)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.registerService(BundleContextImpl.java:433)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.Activator.registerHttpService(Activator.java:81)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.Activator.addProxyServlet(Activator.java:60)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ProxyServlet.init(ProxyServlet.java:40)
    at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.servlet.DelegationServlet.init(DelegationServlet.java:38)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1269)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1182)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:1072)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:5368)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5660)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:145)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1571)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1561)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.wso2.andes.transport.TransportException: Could not bind to /0.0.0.0:5672
    at org.wso2.andes.transport.network.mina.MinaNetworkTransport.accept(MinaNetworkTransport.java:147)
    at org.wso2.andes.server.Broker.startAMQPListener(Broker.java:201)
    at org.wso2.andes.server.Broker.startupImpl(Broker.java:295)
    ... 89 more
Caused by: java.net.BindException: Address already in use
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind0(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:433)
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:425)
    at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketChannelImpl.bind(ServerSocketChannelImpl.java:223)
    at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketAdaptor.bind(ServerSocketAdaptor.java:74)
    at org.apache.mina.transport.socket.nio.SocketAcceptor.registerNew(SocketAcceptor.java:363)
    at org.apache.mina.transport.socket.nio.SocketAcceptor.access$800(SocketAcceptor.java:55)
    at org.apache.mina.transport.socket.nio.SocketAcceptor$Worker.run(SocketAcceptor.java:222)
    at org.apache.mina.util.NamePreservingRunnable.run(NamePreservingRunnable.java:51)
    ... 1 more
[2017-02-22 06:04:46,415]  INFO - ApplicationRegistry Shutting down ApplicationRegistry(org.wso2.andes.server.registry.ConfigurationFileApplicationRegistry@1524f58a)
[2017-02-22 06:04:46,415]  INFO - ApplicationRegistry Shutting down ApplicationRegistry:org.wso2.andes.server.registry.ConfigurationFileApplicationRegistry@1524f58a
[2017-02-22 06:04:46,418]  INFO - PrincipalDatabaseAuthenticationManager Unregistering UserManagementMBean
[2017-02-22 06:04:46,421]  INFO - CarbonServerManager Shutdown hook triggered....
[2017-02-22 06:04:46,426]  INFO - CarbonServerManager Gracefully shutting down WSO2 API Manager...
[2017-02-22 06:04:46,428]  INFO - ServerManagement Starting to switch to maintenance mode...
[2017-02-22 06:04:46,429]  INFO - ServerManagement Stopped all transport listeners
[2017-02-22 06:04:46,429]  INFO - ServerManagement Waiting for request service completion...
[2017-02-22 06:04:46,435]  INFO - ServerManagement All requests have been served.
[2017-02-22 06:04:46,435]  INFO - ServerManagement Waiting for deployment completion...
[2017-02-22 06:04:46,491]  INFO - WebApplication Unloaded webapp: StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/api/am/admin/v0.11]
[2017-02-22 06:04:46,536]  INFO - WebApplication Unloaded webapp: StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/throttle/data/v1]
[2017-02-22 06:04:46,566]  INFO - WebApplication Unloaded webapp: StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/am/sample/calculator/v1]
[2017-02-22 06:04:46,627]  INFO - WebApplication Unloaded webapp: StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/shindig]
[2017-02-22 06:04:46,653]  INFO - WebApplication Unloaded webapp: StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/api/am/publisher/v0.11]
[2017-02-22 06:04:46,682]  INFO - WebApplication Unloaded webapp: StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/api/am/store/v0.11]
[2017-02-22 06:04:46,699]  INFO - WebApplication Unloaded webapp: StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/authenticationendpoint]
[2017-02-22 06:04:46,719]  INFO - WebApplication Unloaded webapp: StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/oauth2]
[2017-02-22 06:04:46,735]  INFO - WebApplication Unloaded webapp: StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/am/sample/pizzashack/v1]
[2017-02-22 06:04:46,756]  INFO - WebApplication Unloaded webapp: StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/client-registration/v0.11]
[2017-02-22 06:04:46,764]  INFO - WebApplication Unloaded webapp: StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/admin]
[2017-02-22 06:04:46,775]  INFO - WebApplication Unloaded webapp: StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/portal]
[2017-02-22 06:04:46,783]  INFO - WebApplication Unloaded webapp: StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/store]
[2017-02-22 06:04:46,791]  INFO - WebApplication Unloaded webapp: StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/publisher]
[2017-02-22 06:04:46,791]  INFO - ServerManagement All deployment tasks have been completed.
[2017-02-22 06:04:46,791]  INFO - ServerManagement Waiting for server task completion...
[2017-02-22 06:04:46,805]  INFO - ServerManagement All server tasks have been completed.
[2017-02-22 06:04:46,805]  INFO - CarbonServerManager Shutting down WSO2 API Manager...
[2017-02-22 06:04:46,811]  INFO - CarbonServerManager Shutting down OSGi framework...
[2017-02-22 06:04:54,812]  INFO - CarbonEventManagementService Starting polling event receivers
[2017-02-22 06:05:15,404]  WARN - BlockingConditionRetriever Failed retrieving Blocking Conditions from remote endpoint: Connection refused. Retrying after 15 seconds...
[2017-02-22 06:05:15,412]  WARN - KeyTemplateRetriever Failed retrieving throttling data from remote endpoint: Connection refused. Retrying after 15 seconds...
[2017-02-22 06:05:17,532]  WARN - AppDeployerServiceComponent Waiting for required OSGi services: org.wso2.carbon.application.deployer.synapse.service.SynapseAppDeployerService,
[2017-02-22 06:05:17,545]  WARN - StartupFinalizerServiceComponent Waiting for required OSGi services: org.wso2.carbon.application.deployer.service.CappDeploymentService,org.wso2.carbon.server.admin.common.IServerAdmin,org.wso2.carbon.throttling.agent.ThrottlingAgent,
[2017-02-22 06:05:30,413]  WARN - BlockingConditionRetriever Failed retrieving Blocking Conditions from remote endpoint: Connection refused. Retrying after 15 seconds...
[2017-02-22 06:05:30,418]  WARN - KeyTemplateRetriever Failed retrieving throttling data from remote endpoint: Connection refused. Retrying after 15 seconds...
[2017-02-22 06:05:44,927]  WARN - SynapseAppDeployerDSComponent Waiting for required OSGi services: org.wso2.carbon.message.processor.service.MessageProcessorDeployerService,org.wso2.carbon.message.store.service.MessageStoreDeployerService,org.wso2.carbon.proxyadmin.service.ProxyDeployerService,
[2017-02-22 06:05:45,415]  WARN - BlockingConditionRetriever Failed retrieving Blocking Conditions from remote endpoint: Connection refused. Retrying after 15 seconds...
[2017-02-22 06:05:45,420]  WARN - KeyTemplateRetriever Failed retrieving throttling data from remote endpoint: Connection refused. Retrying after 15 seconds...
[2017-02-22 06:06:00,419]  WARN - BlockingConditionRetriever Failed retrieving Blocking Conditions from remote endpoint: Connection refused. Retrying after 15 seconds...
[2017-02-22 06:06:00,421]  WARN - KeyTemplateRetriever Failed retrieving throttling data from remote endpoint: Connection refused. Retrying after 15 seconds...
[2017-02-22 06:06:15,422]  WARN - BlockingConditionRetriever Failed retrieving Blocking Conditions from remote endpoint: Connection refused. Retrying after 15 seconds...
[2017-02-22 06:06:15,423]  WARN - KeyTemplateRetriever Failed retrieving throttling data from remote endpoint: Connection refused. Retrying after 15 seconds...
[2017-02-22 06:06:17,531]  WARN - AppDeployerServiceComponent Waiting for required OSGi services: org.wso2.carbon.application.deployer.synapse.service.SynapseAppDeployerService,
[2017-02-22 06:06:17,546]  WARN - StartupFinalizerServiceComponent Waiting for required OSGi services: org.wso2.carbon.application.deployer.service.CappDeploymentService,org.wso2.carbon.server.admin.common.IServerAdmin,org.wso2.carbon.throttling.agent.ThrottlingAgent,
[2017-02-22 06:06:30,425]  WARN - BlockingConditionRetriever Failed retrieving Blocking Conditions from remote endpoint: Connection refused. Retrying after 15 seconds...
[2017-02-22 06:06:30,426]  WARN - KeyTemplateRetriever Failed retrieving throttling data from remote endpoint: Connection refused. Retrying after 15 seconds...
[2017-02-22 06:06:44,926]  WARN - SynapseAppDeployerDSComponent Waiting for required OSGi services: org.wso2.carbon.message.processor.service.MessageProcessorDeployerService,org.wso2.carbon.message.store.service.MessageStoreDeployerService,org.wso2.carbon.proxyadmin.service.ProxyDeployerService,
[2017-02-22 06:06:45,428]  WARN - BlockingConditionRetriever Failed retrieving Blocking Conditions from remote endpoint: Connection refused. Retrying after 15 seconds...
[2017-02-22 06:06:45,428]  WARN - KeyTemplateRetriever Failed retrieving throttling data from remote endpoint: Connection refused. Retrying after 15 seconds...
[2017-02-22 06:07:00,430]  WARN - BlockingConditionRetriever Failed retrieving Blocking Conditions from remote endpoint: Connection refused. Retrying after 15 seconds...
[2017-02-22 06:07:00,431]  WARN - KeyTemplateRetriever Failed retrieving throttling data from remote endpoint: Connection refused. Retrying after 15 seconds...
[2017-02-22 06:07:15,434]  WARN - BlockingConditionRetriever Failed retrieving Blocking Conditions from remote endpoint: Connection refused. Retrying after 15 seconds...
[2017-02-22 06:07:15,434]  WARN - KeyTemplateRetriever Failed retrieving throttling data from remote endpoint: Connection refused. Retrying after 15 seconds...
[2017-02-22 06:07:17,531]  WARN - AppDeployerServiceComponent Waiting for required OSGi services: org.wso2.carbon.application.deployer.synapse.service.SynapseAppDeployerService,
[2017-02-22 06:07:17,545]  WARN - StartupFinalizerServiceComponent Waiting for required OSGi services: org.wso2.carbon.application.deployer.service.CappDeploymentService,org.wso2.carbon.server.admin.common.IServerAdmin,org.wso2.carbon.throttling.agent.ThrottlingAgent,
[2017-02-22 06:07:30,438]  WARN - BlockingConditionRetriever Failed retrieving Blocking Conditions from remote endpoint: Connection refused. Retrying after 15 seconds...
[2017-02-22 06:07:30,438]  WARN - KeyTemplateRetriever Failed retrieving throttling data from remote endpoint: Connection refused. Retrying after 15 seconds...
[2017-02-22 06:07:36,930]  INFO - SynapseTaskManager Shutting down the task manager
[2017-02-22 06:07:44,926]  WARN - SynapseAppDeployerDSComponent Waiting for required OSGi services: org.wso2.carbon.message.processor.service.MessageProcessorDeployerService,org.wso2.carbon.message.store.service.MessageStoreDeployerService,org.wso2.carbon.proxyadmin.service.ProxyDeployerService,
[2017-02-22 06:07:45,440]  WARN - BlockingConditionRetriever Failed retrieving Blocking Conditions from remote endpoint: Connection refused. Retrying after 15 seconds...
[2017-02-22 06:07:45,442]  WARN - KeyTemplateRetriever Failed retrieving throttling data from remote endpoint: Connection refused. Retrying after 15 seconds...
[2017-02-22 06:08:00,444]  WARN - KeyTemplateRetriever Failed retrieving throttling data from remote endpoint: Connection refused. Retrying after 15 seconds...
[2017-02-22 06:08:00,445]  WARN - BlockingConditionRetriever Failed retrieving Blocking Conditions from remote endpoint: Connection refused. Retrying after 15 seconds...
[2017-02-22 06:08:15,452]  WARN - KeyTemplateRetriever Failed retrieving throttling data from remote endpoint: Connection refused. Retrying after 15 seconds...
[2017-02-22 06:08:15,452]  WARN - BlockingConditionRetriever Failed retrieving Blocking Conditions from remote endpoint: Connection refused. Retrying after 15 seconds...
[2017-02-22 06:08:17,531]  WARN - AppDeployerServiceComponent Waiting for required OSGi services: org.wso2.carbon.application.deployer.synapse.service.SynapseAppDeployerService,
[2017-02-22 06:08:17,545]  WARN - StartupFinalizerServiceComponent Waiting for required OSGi services: org.wso2.carbon.application.deployer.service.CappDeploymentService,org.wso2.carbon.server.admin.common.IServerAdmin,org.wso2.carbon.throttling.agent.ThrottlingAgent,
[2017-02-22 06:08:30,456]  WARN - KeyTemplateRetriever Failed retrieving throttling data from remote endpoint: Connection refused. Retrying after 15 seconds...
[2017-02-22 06:08:30,456]  WARN - BlockingConditionRetriever Failed retrieving Blocking Conditions from remote endpoint: Connection refused. Retrying after 15 seconds...
[2017-02-22 06:08:44,927]  WARN - SynapseAppDeployerDSComponent Waiting for required OSGi services: org.wso2.carbon.message.processor.service.MessageProcessorDeployerService,org.wso2.carbon.message.store.service.MessageStoreDeployerService,org.wso2.carbon.proxyadmin.service.ProxyDeployerService,
[2017-02-22 06:08:45,458] ERROR - BlockingConditionRetriever Exception when retrieving Blocking Conditions from remote endpoint 
java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:350)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.connect(SSLSocketImpl.java:668)
    at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLSocketFactory.connectSocket(SSLSocketFactory.java:522)
    at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLSocketFactory.connectSocket(SSLSocketFactory.java:401)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:178)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPoolEntry.open(AbstractPoolEntry.java:144)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPooledConnAdapter.open(AbstractPooledConnAdapter.java:131)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.tryConnect(DefaultRequestDirector.java:610)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:445)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.doExecute(AbstractHttpClient.java:863)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:82)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:106)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:57)
    at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.gateway.throttling.util.BlockingConditionRetriever.retrieveBlockConditionsData(BlockingConditionRetriever.java:79)
    at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.gateway.throttling.util.BlockingConditionRetriever.loadBlockingConditionsFromWebService(BlockingConditionRetriever.java:105)
    at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.gateway.throttling.util.BlockingConditionRetriever.run(BlockingConditionRetriever.java:51)
    at java.util.TimerThread.mainLoop(Timer.java:555)
    at java.util.TimerThread.run(Timer.java:505)
[2017-02-22 06:08:45,458] ERROR - KeyTemplateRetriever Exception when retrieving throttling data from remote endpoint 
java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:350)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.connect(SSLSocketImpl.java:668)
    at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLSocketFactory.connectSocket(SSLSocketFactory.java:522)
    at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLSocketFactory.connectSocket(SSLSocketFactory.java:401)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:178)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPoolEntry.open(AbstractPoolEntry.java:144)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPooledConnAdapter.open(AbstractPooledConnAdapter.java:131)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.tryConnect(DefaultRequestDirector.java:610)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:445)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.doExecute(AbstractHttpClient.java:863)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:82)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:106)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:57)
    at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.gateway.throttling.util.KeyTemplateRetriever.retrieveKeyTemplateData(KeyTemplateRetriever.java:83)
    at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.gateway.throttling.util.KeyTemplateRetriever.loadKeyTemplatesFromWebService(KeyTemplateRetriever.java:111)
    at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.gateway.throttling.util.KeyTemplateRetriever.run(KeyTemplateRetriever.java:54)
    at java.util.TimerThread.mainLoop(Timer.java:555)
    at java.util.TimerThread.run(Timer.java:505)
Exception in thread "Timer-5" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at java.util.Objects.requireNonNull(Objects.java:203)
    at java.util.Arrays$ArrayList.<init>(Arrays.java:3813)
    at java.util.Arrays.asList(Arrays.java:3800)
    at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.gateway.throttling.util.KeyTemplateRetriever.loadKeyTemplatesFromWebService(KeyTemplateRetriever.java:111)
    at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.gateway.throttling.util.KeyTemplateRetriever.run(KeyTemplateRetriever.java:54)
    at java.util.TimerThread.mainLoop(Timer.java:555)
    at java.util.TimerThread.run(Timer.java:505)
[2017-02-22 06:09:16,963]  INFO - BinaryDataReceiverServiceComponent Binary Data Receiver server shutting down...
[2017-02-22 06:09:16,964]  INFO - BinaryDataReceiver Stopping Binary Server..
[2017-02-22 06:09:17,531]  WARN - AppDeployerServiceComponent Waiting for required OSGi services: org.wso2.carbon.application.deployer.synapse.service.SynapseAppDeployerService
```

Comment: Based on the error log, it says 5672 port is already used. Check the server 5672 port is available. If you are running another app with that port, try closing that. Otherwise you can start the WSO2 server with ./wso2server.sh -DportOffset=1

Comment: using -DportOffset=1 allowed the server to start up. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 3):

I was running Java 17 SDK and got this same problem. Solved this by running the WSO2 script with Java 11 SDK instead.

You can either :

1. Change your JAVA_HOME variable value
2. Create a new environment variable pointing to Java 11 SDK and replace recursively inside the WSO2 directory JAVA_HOME with the new environment variable you have created

Answer (score 1):

This is because port 5672 is occupied at the time when the API Manager server starts up. You can have 2 options I can think of to proceed with,

1. Change the default port offset.

   - You can either start the API manager server with -DportOffset=[offset] (ex- -DportOffset=1) or change the  value in /repository/conf to a value other than 0 and start the server.
2. Stop the existing process of already occupied server

   - Without worrying about port offset, you can run the API Manager server on 5672 port for AMQP transport.
   - Search the process of occupied port (5672 in this case)

> netstat -nlp|grep 5672

Output should looks like something below

> tcp   0    0 0.0.0.0:5672     0.0.0.0:*     LISTEN      6187/java

- Kill the process

> kill -9 [Process_ID]

(here, 6187)

Then start the server and you won't see the exception anymore.

Answer (score 1):

I was trying from long time. RMQ was running in my system.

Got to **C:\Program Files (x86)\RabbitMQ Server\rabbitmq_server-3.3.4\sbin** and run

```
rabbitmq-service.bat stop
```

Answer (score 0):

Port 5672 is needed for API Manager, from your exception trace, that port is occupied by another process.

Normally [RabbitMQ uses 5672](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12792856/what-ports-does-rabbitmq-use), if that's the case you have to shut down that process. If you have another API Manager running on the physical node, then you have to offset the port with `-DportOffset=1`

Answer (score 0):

There's a problem with your port 5672,this port is already in use by some other process. So shutdown your wso2 process by ps -ef|grep wso2 and then kill -9 . 
Then change your port by following this link and start wso2 api manager again.
https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM200/Changing+the+Default+Ports+with+Offset

Answer (score 0):

As Tanvi and Abimaran said, Port 5672 is used for queuing. It's very common to get this error when configuring two nodes in one machine for trying cluster. If this port has been used by another application, and you can't shut that application down, then you can change

```
connectionfactory.TopicConnectionFactory = amqp://admin:admin@clientid/carbon?brokerlist='tcp://localhost:5672'

connectionfactory.QueueConnectionFactory = amqp://admin:admin@clientID/test?brokerlist='tcp://localhost:5672'
```

to another port for API manager in (/repository/config/jndi.properties).

Answer (score 0):

You could change the default ports with an offset. So go to :

```
 deployment.toml
```

and for example change the following config:

```
 [server]
 offset=1
```

so port no 5672 will be change to 5673.